# DNS - List all entries

Tags: domain-name-system

is it possible, to list all entries a domain has on a DNS-Server? (Without having administrative access to the NS-Server)

I know that the domain should have sub-domains - I just do not know what they are named and what IP they are assigned to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try query AXFR record:

```
$ dig example.com @nsserver AXFR
```

[DNS zone transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer):

> DNS zone transfer, also sometimes known by its (most common) opcode mnemonic AXFR, is a type of DNS transaction. It is one of the many mechanisms available for administrators to employ for replicating the databases containing the DNS data across a set of DNS servers. Zone transfer comes in two flavors, full (opcode AXFR) and incremental (IXFR). Nearly universal at one time, it is now becoming less popular in favor of the use of other database replication mechanisms that modern DNS server packages provide.

Comment: That would imply a very badly setup DNS server!

Comment: Few servers offer transfer to the public anymore.  They generally only allow transfer to secondary servers and other authorized hosts.  Unless your host is trusted, it is unlikely the server will give the information you are looking for.